# Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using Google Maps API v3 for some time without an API key, and it worked well.
It still works, but I get a warning in the console:

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

I include the script the standard way:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

And `google.maps.version` indicates that I'm using 3.24.2.

In the Google documentation I can only see the different ways to obtain a key, but there is no indication if it's required or not. I noticed the warning today and I'm quite sure it didn't appear a few weeks ago.

Everything is working fine for now, but I'm afraid that maps access without an API key will be ceased in the future. I'm reluctant to register for a key if I don't absolutely need to.

Should I worry about it?

Comment: Accepted answer is not working anymore.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Creating and using the key is the way to go.
The usage is free until your application reaches 25.000 calls per day on 90 consecutive days.

BTW.: In the google Developer documentation it says you shall add the api key as option {key:yourKey} when calling the API to create new instances.
This however doesn't shush the console warning. 
You have to add the key as a parameter when including the api.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourKEYhere"></script>
```

Get the key here: [GoogleApiKey Generation site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer for this question. Seems silly that someone would ask why the API key says it's missing if they never placed it there to begin with.

Comment: Great! But which is the direct link to generate the API Key? Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
Included the link into the answer now

Comment: i have the same issue, but i don't know how to add this key, what is the nature of the key and how to choose it.

Comment: the key is a string you get on the site linked in my answer. You add it to the api load url as a GET var. see above

Comment: So if you add the api key you will be billed for api calls over 25000 per day, but if you don't add api key, can you still use google maps even exceeding the quota?!

Answer (score 40):

A key currently still is not required ("required" in the meaning "it will not work without"), but I think there is a good reason for the warning.

But in the documentation you may read now : ["All JavaScript API applications require authentication."](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

I'm sure that it's planned for the future , that Javascript API Applications will not work without a key(as it has been in V2).

You better use a key when you want to be sure that your application will still work in 1 or 2 years.

Comment: For those coming here after June 2016, see @Max answer below - you DO need an api key. This answer is obsolete

Comment: For those coming here in August 2016, all my google js-api maps are still working fine (but yes, i have warnings)

Comment: @Devtrix.net API keys are required for new applications, existing apps are exempted for now, as long as you don't change your url etc.

Comment: where to add the key?

Comment: @HosMercury https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#specify-a-key-when-loading-the-api

Comment: This answer is actually not exactly obsolete, because for some APIs the warning is still pops up AND a key is still not required.
(I get the warning when using the Google GeoChart, that calls the Maps API internally, without setting up any Google API project).

Comment: 2018 still fine without a key

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and I found out that if you add the URL param `?v=3` you won't get the warning message anymore:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/7rmgw1m4/1/)

As pointed out in the comments by @Zia Ul Rehman Mughal

> Turns out specifying this means you are referring to old frozen version 3.0 not the latest version. Frozen old versions are not updated with bug fixes or anything. But this is good to mention though.
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#the-frozen-version

## Update 07-Jun-2016

This solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This is interesting, can you explain some background why you added it and what is causing warning to go away?

Comment: Turns out specifying this means you are referring to old frozen version 3.0 not the latest version. Frozen old versions are not updated with bug fixes or anything. But this is good to mention though. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#the-frozen-version

Comment: Turns out your fiddle actually throws the warning

Comment: @Max you are right. It seems the behavior changed by now.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry,drawing   I want to use this api. Does this need any api key??

Comment: For whatever reason, that solution still works for me on the domain, but it doesn't if it go to the index.html file directly.

Comment: Thanks you saved me @Alvaro!

Answer (score 8):

Google maps requires an API key for new projects since june 2016. For more information take a look at the [Google Developers Blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html). Also more information in german you'll find at this [blog post](https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/google-maps-api-nur-noch-mit-key/) from the clickstorm Blog.