# Placepicker.js is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.placepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".placepicker").placepicker();
    }); // END document.ready
</script>
            <input class="placepicker form-control" name="location" placeholder="location"/>
```

Please help me. It's not working properly.

Comment: console error ?

Comment: there is nothing coming to the console. Only some api warning is occurring.

Comment: I think this js `placepicker.js` must has dependency of `jquery.min.js`. Possibly. So please load `jquery.js` prior to load any js

Comment: jquery-1.11.1.min.js is being used too.

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: these are the console resopnses

Comment: try with `sensor=false`.

Comment: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
util.js (line 208)
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: again it's not working.

Comment: try with this sample code http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp

Comment: sir, i am not showing map. i need place picker.

Comment: https://github.com/benignware/jquery-placepicker

Comment: #vinit sir, are you there?

Comment: Yeah bro. Let me see first.

Comment: ok sir. i am waitting.

Comment: I didn't find any issue when I clone it. I've researched a lot about the APIKEYs error. I've worked on before without authentication and it worked. Even it is working in sample GIT code. It's hard to track the issue without watching your code. You can show me a `plunker` or `jsFiddle`. But first try `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>` In case it will not work just go with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890582/google-maps-api-warning-noapikeys and in last please provide me your fiddle.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC2OUsif2yH9k_Q-f-Lei6eYWrCAosEse0&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>


i used this. Now it's working fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

you have to provide api key only, then it will work fine.